# Firebase Limitation overcome in GA

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

In Firebase, It consists of several ​events ​which are sent along with additional ​key parameters​, some of those events contain around 30 key parameters and even more.
For Google Analytics this is not an issue since an event can be set up to be sent with 200 custom dimensions, nevertheless we are now required and forced by Google to use ​Firebase for apps, Firebase has a limitation of 25 parameters per event.

- How do we proceed in case we only care about Google Analytics data.
- Based on the solution of the above, what would happen in Firebase events?
- Is there a way to have the events sent to Google analytics as well as Firebase ​without
  causing any changes in Google Analytics? ​If so, how!?
- Some of the events are reaching Firebase but not Google Analytics,
  what could possibly be the reason, how should someone start an investigation?

Comment: too much questions in one and the last is not clear.

Comment: Hi Michele, How about the first one? is it clear?